# Non detecting event "messageDelete" on discord.js

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I was scripting a log system on a discord bot where I wanted it to show the messages which get deleted.
I coded this:

```
client.on("messageDelete", async (message) => {
    const logsChannel = message.guild.channels.cache.get("1104432785281777704")
    console.log("Detected message deleted")
    if (logsChannel && message.channel !== logsChannel){
      const embed = new EmbedBuilder()
      .setTitle("Message deleted")
      .setURL(message.url)
      .setColor("DarkVividPink")
      .setDescription("Someone deleted the message sent by <@"+message.author.id+">.")
      .setFields([
        {
          name: "Content:",
          value: message.content
        },
        {
          name: "Author:",
          value: "<@"+message.author.id+">"
        }
      ])
      .setFooter({iconURL: message.guild.iconURL(), text: message.guild.name})
      .setTimestamp()
      logsChannel.send({embeds: [embed]})
    }
  })
```

But for some reason the event don't get fired...
This are my intents:

```
intents: [GatewayIntentBits.Guilds, GatewayIntentBits.GuildMessages, GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent, GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessages, GatewayIntentBits.DirectMessageReactions, GatewayIntentBits.GuildModeration, GatewayIntentBits.GuildEmojisAndStickers]
```

I don't know where is the problem and I will thank if someone can help me.
Thanks.

I have checked all the intents which may have any relation as `GatewayIntentBits.MessageContent` but that didn't work.
The bot also have permission to chat in the channel where it should log and read access on all the channels.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `partials` in your client constructor:

```js
partials: [
    Partials.Message,
    Partials.Channel,
    Partials.GuildMember,
    Partials.User,
    Partials.Reaction
]
```